# display locationcode instead of Location in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display in the report the LocationCode instead of the Location from the same table [image]

Edit:
Code (as user added it to an answer):

```
select LC.LocationCode 
from LocationMain LM 
left outer join 
(Select Location,LocationCode from LocMaster AS LR) ON LR.Location=LM.Location
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.? Hv u tried anything?

Comment: I am voting to close this as it's unclear and low quality.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code? Sorry, but that's just basic of SQL. StackOverflow is not free code writing tool

Comment: @Caldazar:Ur question has answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select LC.LocationCode
from LocationMain LM
left outer join (Select Location,LocationCode from LocMaster AS LR) ON LR.Location=LM.Location

Comment: I added answer, with correction to your code. This code that you have added should have been  posted as edit to your question, not as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Just don't select the column in your query. `SELECT t.ID, t.LocationCode FROM yourTableName AS t`

Answer (score 1):

Here's correction to your code. You shouldn't have added second Select statement:

```
select LC.LocationCode 
doci from LocationMain LM 
left outer join LocMaster AS LR ON LR.Location=LM.Location
```